# Computing average from relation with null values in SQLite

Tags: sql, database, sqlite, subquery

I'm having a hard time computing the average in SQL when I have null fields in a table. I want to include fields which have null and replace them with the number 10 before calculating the average. Suppose I have the following relation:

```
x  |  y
-------
j  | 3
k  | 4
l  | NULL
n  | 55
```

My logic so far has been to take all the fields y where there are null values and take the sum and count of items in that table, and then take the sum and count of fields who do not have null values. From this, I combine both sums and counts and compute the average. So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT sum1+sum2/c1+c2 
FROM (SELECT sum(cap) as sum1, count(*) as c1 FROM courses) 
UNION (SELECT SUM(null_fields) as sum2, c2 
FROM (SELECT 10 as null_fields, count(*) as c2 FROM courses 
WHERE cap IS NULL))
```

However, this doesn't work. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1):

Use `coalesce()`:

```
select avg(coalesce(cap, 10))
from courses;
```

Comment: Is there any way to do this without coalesce? I'd prefer to do it the long and dirty way just for the sake of learning.

Answer (score 0):

You must not use parentheses inside a [compound query](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html#compound), and the column names of a compound query are determined only by the first query inside it. UNION removes duplicates, which you do not want if the NULL- and non-NULL partial results happen to have the same values. And the compound query returns two rows, so you have to run an additional aggregation:

```
SELECT sum(sum1) / sum(c1)
FROM (SELECT sum(cap) as sum1,
             count(*) as c1
      FROM courses
      UNION ALL
      SELECT SUM(null_fields) as sum2,
             c2
      FROM (SELECT 10 as null_fields,
                   count(*) as c2
            FROM courses 
            WHERE cap IS NULL)
     );
```

And the inner subquery is superfluous, but if you'd want to have an efficient or maintainable query, you'd use Gordon's answer.